# Hive metastore dropping connections for every four or six hours

Tags: mysql, hive, hikaricp, hdp

**Hive Metastore is going down for every four or six hours with error message like **

```
HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6e3a8be9 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

hive beeline connection type : tcp 
hive version : 3.1
HDP version : 3.1
MySql version : 5.7.25
Mysql-java-jar version : 8.0.13
Hikaripoool version : 2.6.1

I have tried setting the connection properties autoReconnect in metastore mysql jdbc connection  but that did not help

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because of the driver version mismatch from the Ambari MySQL version to 
mysql jdbc driver version in the hive metastore .

I have deleted the driver and copied the suitable driver to the hive-metastore lib to resolve the issue.